# Double scientific notation format 10th power C#

Tags: c#, string, types, format, double

I am having `double value = 30308950000;`

I want to display it like `3.03x10^10`

How can I achieve it using C#?

I have tried

```
double value = 30308950000;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.###E+0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

output = `3.03E+10`

I dont want the `3.03E+10` format but  `3.03x10^10`.
Thanks

Comment: How can someone down-vote this question? That is absolutely not a trivia! The accepted answer is awful.

Comment: People who down voted this should also left a comment here. So we can get to a better solution.

Comment: @Orace this question shouldn't be down-voted - yes, but what exactly is `awful` at my answer? Please describe yourself and I'll do my best correcting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fix:

```
double value = 30308950000;
Console.WriteLine(
    value.ToString("0.###E+0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        .Replace("E-","x10^-")
        .Replace("E+","x10^"));
```

Shout out to Jon Skeet! :)

Comment: That only works when the result really has E+10, of course. It won't work (as written) for E+9 etc. If you're going to have a solution that only works for the sample value, you might as well change it to `Console.WriteLine("3.03x10^10")`

Comment: That still seems to be a little over the top. Why not just replace `E+` with `x10^` and `E-` with `x10^-`?

Comment: Because I love math :) But yeah you're right again. Fixed it -

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for as an output. Thanks @JonSkeet and TheRealVira :)

Comment: @TheRealVira, first, I didn't down-vote your answer, For me It's awful because it didn't scale well. If I had to use it I will put it in an extension method but use it will be hard. `E-` and `E+` string are not reserved to number and you take the risk to replace them. Like in "Fe-O potential : 3.03E-4 u".

Comment: @Orace, I thought about that too, but came to the conclusion that this wont matter. Why? Because we'll take double as value and not a string. If the question was `"How should I convert a string containing a double to a scientific format by the power of 10?"`, I'd suggest splitting your string, so you could work with the double by itself and than append it back together.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, [NumberFormarInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't provide any **ExponentialSign** parameter.

That it, the [Exponential Format Specifier (E)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#EFormatString) use only NegativeSign, NumberDecimalSeparator and PositiveSign information from the [NumberFormarInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

To do it *"in the pattern"*, you have to use your own implementation of [ICustomFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.icustomformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414873/iformatprovider-scientific-conversion-from-double-to-string-number-of-digits).