# C# - I need to display a variable with an exponential

Tags: c#

C# - I need to display a variable with an exponential number but this number is dynamic for example I display 5² and I can change 2 by 6

Comment: What UI technology are you using?  How do you *currently* display values?

Comment: Where on winforms or WPF?

Comment: How do you store the variable?

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785578/double-scientific-notation-format-10th-power-c-sharp

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. You can use this [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) in order to make sure your question is not missing anything important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use unicode code points:

**Superscript digits**

\u2070\u00b9\u00b2\u00b3\u2074\u2075\u2076\u2077\u2078\u2079

**Subscript digits**

U+2080 to U+2089

Example:

```
var superscriptstring = "C\u2074";
var subscriptstring = "C\u2081";
```